# Why does Adyen Alipay (test env) url show ILLEGAL_SIGN error?

Tags: adyen

I've been attempting to integrate with Adyen and was successful on some of the payment methods like Diners, JCB, Unionpay.  However for Alipay, I've been getting this `ILLEGAL_SIGN` sign error and I can't find anything in the documentation related to this.  Following this documentation: https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/alipay/api-only, on `/payments` call, Adyen will return a url.  After going to this url, a page with `ILLEGAL_SIGN` error is shown.  What could have caused this?
[image: illegal_sign]

I tried Adyen's sample rails app (https://github.com/adyen-examples/adyen-rails-online-payments).  In this sample app, the other payments are ok but for Alipay it also gets this `ILLEGAL_SIGN` error.

Comment: Contacted support and got a response that they updated some settings.  And now it is fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adyen sandbox pages are not maintained by them, therefore it is quite likely that there is something between Adyen and Alipay that is causing this problem. I would just [contact their support](https://www.adyen.help/hc/en-us/requests/new) and ask them to take a look to it.

Comment: Hey @hfc. Adyen samples are definitely maintained by us :). It is indeed a good idea to contact support if the request is urgent. I'll have a look nonetheless